# How can I draw a model with a color on WP7?

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

How can I draw a model with a color (and still be aware of the lighting)?

This is really straight forward when you can use shaders, but on Windows Phone you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this property useful: [`BasicEffect.DiffuseColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect.diffusecolor.aspx)